# Extract audio file details from URL(mp3 file)

Tags: android, kotlin, audio-streaming, jaudiotagger

- To get audio file(mp3) details from URL I am using `JAudioTagger` in my android app but I am unable to get details.

My Code:

```
val audioFile = AudioFileIO.read(Objects.requireNonNull(File("https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3")))
    
   Log.d(TAG, "title: ${audioFile.tag.getFirst(FieldKey.TITLE)}")
   Log.d(TAG, "artist: ${audioFile.tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ARTIST)}")
   Log.d(TAG, "album: ${audioFile.tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ALBUM)}") 
   Log.d(TAG, "duration: ${audioFile.audioHeader.trackLength * 1000}")
```

- I am getting exception. Guide me in the right direction.

Comment: As far as I know, Jaudiotagger does not support online audio streams

Comment: Do you know any class or library that supports online audio streams for android?

Comment: @AndroidDev Your MP3 file doesn't have `title` or `album`. Do you think telling about the exception might help others to help you?